# What launch option do I set to start DOOM 4 straight into multiplayer mode?

Tags: doom-2016

Starting DOOM 4 brings you through a bunch of naggy screens before bringing you to a screen to choose which game mode you want. Are there launch options to go straight to multiplayer mode?

[image]

Comment: Looking for an answer myself. In the meantime, the parameter "+com_skipIntroVideo 1" (without quotes) will skip those naggy intro screens/movies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable "com_gameMode" controls the mode in which the game runs at. It is described as:

> determines asset load pattern and runtime behavior for production
>   builds only

There are 6 values available:

- 0 - ALL - all modes presumabely, although it didn't work for me as intended. Clicking Multiplayer restarted the game immediately, without any confirmation.
- 1 - SP - singleplayer mode, the default value
- 2 - MP - multiplayer mode
- 3 - SNAP - the snapmap mode I guess, never tried it yet
- 4 - SHELL - no idea. Maybe just the game shell without any modes?
- 5 - MOD - for mods?

Therefore, if you want to start in multiplayer mode you need to pass the parameter:

```
+com_gameMode 2
```

Initially, I thought this is idiotic. On second thought, this seems as a mechanism to avoid loading unused assets. It could be done better though, upon actually clicking on the mode itself and not at start...